# Ionic deploy fails

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Pro.deploy.checkAndApply to update my app.

It runs and fails, the error is:

`SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1 : {"rejection":"/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/www.zip (No such file or directory)","promise":{"__zone_symbol__state":0,"__zone_symbol__value":"/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/www.zip (No such file or directory)"},"zone":{"_properties":{"isAngularZone":true},"_parent":{"_properties":{},"_parent":null,"_name":"<root>","_zoneDelegate":{"_taskCounts":{"microTask":0,"macroTask":0,"eventTask":0},"_parentDelegate":null,"_forkZS":null,"_forkDlgt":null,"_forkCurrZone":null,"_interceptZS":null,"_interceptDlgt":null,"_interceptCurrZone":null,"_invokeZS":null,"_invokeDlgt":null,"_invokeCurrZone":null,"_handleErrorZS":null,"_handleErrorDlgt":null,"_handleErrorCurrZone":null,"_scheduleTaskZS":null,"_scheduleTaskDlgt":null,"_scheduleTaskCurrZone":null,"_invokeTaskZS":null,"_invokeTaskDlgt":null,"_invokeTaskCurrZone":null,"_cancelTaskZS":null,"_cancelTaskDlgt":null,"_cancelTaskCurrZone":null,"_hasTaskZS":null,"_hasTaskDlgt":null,"_hasTaskDlgtOwner":null,"_hasTaskCurrZone":null}},"_name":"angular","_zoneDelegate":{"_taskCounts":{"microTask":0,"macroTask":0,"eventTask":38},"_forkZS":null,"_forkDlgt":null,"_interceptZS":null,"_interceptDlgt":null,"_invokeZS":{"name":"angular"},"_scheduleTaskZS":{"name":""}}},"task":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}`

I’m running it on android
ionic info:
```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.1
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : Linux 3.19
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

```

Please help me understand what went wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I also have this issue. Please help.